# Remove the extra space between table rows on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a HTML table with

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

It looks fine in IE and Firefox but on Chrome it is adding extra space between the rows. I can't get rid of these spaces. I tried cellpadding=0 and cellspacing=0 but that removes all spaces which is not what I want.
In Chrome the table is now extending the maximum height which is bad.

[image]

ok here's the example, left is Chrome, right is Firefox. Same code, regular table, why is there so much space added by Chrome and how to avoid this?

Comment: I've got the latest version (Version 24.0.1312.56 m) and it worked for me. I bet there is something else that causes this problem. Have a look at: http://www.css4you.de/example/border-collapse.html

Comment: the issue is not as described on the site. There is a space between the rows, which is fine, but in Chrome the space is twice as big (???)

Comment: you mean that this site returns two different results for eg. ff and chrome? maybe there is something wrong with the default font?

Comment: Roughly how much space is being added in pixels?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your image, i figured out, it's maybe not the TABLE **it's the SELECT**

Also, plain has plain, no reset to your .css .. Of course it will appear different from each and every browser.

Provide the html and css, create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: yeah I understand it will differ on every browser, but even when removing ALL spaces there's still a space in the Chrome table.

Comment: then, it's BROWSER SPECIFIC styling, nothing else and NOT a bug.

Comment: you don't have to shout LOL, I've been a software developer for 15 years, I even worked with Netscape Navigator 1 haha. why would the Chrome team add lots of dummy space between elements when knowing it will mess up many pages' layout. My question was, how can this be overridden?  but appearantly it can't....